# JavaScript function not working in Firefox and Safari (just in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I have a page with already other JavaScripts correctly working... apart from this one:

```
<script>
function add(numDaysToAdd) {
    var data_in = new Date (document.WADAInsertForm.data_in.value);
    var data_out = data_in.setDate(data_in.getDate()+numDaysToAdd);
    var final_day = data_out.getDate();
    var final_month = data_out.getMonth() + 1;
    var final_year = data_out.getFullYear();

    document.WADAInsertForm.data_out.value = final_year+'-'+final_month+'-'+final_day;
    
    }
</script>
```

This script is triggered by an `OnChange` call on a checkbox together with a `OnClick` event. To clarify:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="Insurance plan: 1 month" id="product" onClick="this.form.price.value='41.40'" onChange="add(+30)">
```

When I test the page in Chrome it does all the homeworks: insert the price value in the "price" field and update the "data_out" field with the proper value.

When I do the same in Firefox and Safari... it works only the "price" setting.

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange="add(+30)"
```

Here **+30** doesn't represent any String or any Integer in your script it would through a type error, to add days to the current date you could use this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function AddDays(toAdd) {
        if (!toAdd || toAdd == '' || isNaN(toAdd)) return;
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + parseInt(toAdd));

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    }
</script>
---------------------- UI ---------------
    <div id="result">
    </div>
    <input type="text" value="0" onkeyup="AddDays(this.value);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` isn't valid. Use `onclick`.

And I find it strange to have both `onclick` and `onchange` on a checkbox. You should include your `onclick` in the `onchange`.